# Changing color of text during scroll

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a header.
Initially, all the words in it are black, but while scrolling, the color should change, how can I do that? Are there any ready-made solutions?
There is such a code from template but it is displayed poorly, because it is on the bootstrap.

```
    .header_area {
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 99;
      top: 0;
      padding: 0 4%;
    }

    .menu_area .navbar-brand {
      font-size: 72px;
      font-weight: 700;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
      line-height: 1;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .menu_area .navbar-brand:hover,
    .menu_area .navbar-brand:focus {
      color: #fff;
    }

    .menu_area {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }

    .menu_area #nav .nav-link {
      color: #fff;
      display: block;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 500;
      border-radius: 30px;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
      -o-transition-duration: 500ms;
      transition-duration: 500ms;
      padding: 35px 15px;
    }

    .menu_area nav ul li>a:hover {
      color: #fb397d;
    }

    .header_area.sticky {
      background: rgb(0, 122, 223);
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(77deg, rgb(0, 122, 223) 0%, rgb(0, 236, 188) 100%);
      background: -o-linear-gradient(77deg, rgb(0, 122, 223) 0%, rgb(0, 236, 188) 100%);
      background: -ms-linear-gradient(77deg, rgb(0, 122, 223) 0%, rgb(0, 236, 188) 100%);
      background: linear-gradient(77deg, rgb(0, 122, 223) 0%, rgb(0, 236, 188) 100%);
      height: 70px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 99;
    }

    .header_area.sticky .menu_area .navbar-brand {
      font-size: 50px;
    }

    .header_area.sticky .menu_area #nav .nav-link {
      padding: 23px 15px;
    }

    .header_area.sticky .navbar {
      padding: 0;
    }

<!-- language: lang-html -->

    <header class="header_area animated">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
            <div class="menu_area">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                  <img src="img/image.png" style="margin-top: -15px;width: 48px; height: 38px;">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ca-navbar" aria-controls="ca-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ca-navbar">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="nav" style="margin-right: -220px;">
                    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#home" style="color: #000;">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#about" style="color: #000;">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#features" style="color: #000;"></a>Text</li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#application" style="color: #000;">Application</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#support" style="color: #000;">Support</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact" style="color: #000;">Contact</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
```

so, for example you can look at this web site colorlib.com/preview/#massive, where text in header are white, but when I scroll I need to see another image and black text. How can I do that?

Comment: You already have the active class when you reach different sections. Try to add a class to the header based on the active menu item and then change the colors using CSS.

Comment: under what condition do you really need the text to change color? the example site's header's options change their styling based on if you are at the height of it's section, is that what you need?

Comment: Doing this with css only is a real pain in the ass.. With javascript it's much easier with the onScroll event.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp

Comment: @BrianH. when I scroll and header is down I need to see white text(home,about,contact etc)

Comment: @Aslam can you show it on some example,please?